# What is the difference between “FachHochschule” and “Universität/Technische Universität”, especially for master degrees?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, germany

I want to enter Germany for my master's and want to do Job there. I don't want to do a Ph.D. I am having a hard time choosing between FH and TU. My main goal is to do Job after my master's so which type of Institution I should choose. I have heard FH helps to give practical exposure according to Industry (mine is IT) and TU gives deep and thorough Knowledge(Bookish knowledge) about the same. Please help me out I will be applying for the Winter semester this year.

Comment: You are basically right, though also universities (especially technical universities) usually have some partners and projects in industry. The general perception among Germans is that a university degree is higher than a FH degree, but in theory they are equivalent. Your choice is, however, up to you alone - do what fits better with your learning style (unless you want to stay in academia, then you should probably go to university - though even this is not a must). Keep an eye at different universities/FH's, as they might differ as well in their teaching style and programs.

Comment: @Mark I believe your comment should be an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between “Hochschule” and “Universität/Technische Universität”, especially for master degrees?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72614/what-is-the-difference-between-hochschule-and-universit%c3%a4t-technische-universi)