# Pros and Cons of joining a Private university or Hochschule compare to a public university in Germany as a postdoc

Tags: postdocs, computer-science, faculty-application, germany

I am in the last year of my PhD(from a public university), my funding is over, and I am looking for a postdoc(officially research assistant). I have an offer from Zeppelin University. Also, a discussion is going on with a technical Hochschule. I am from a computer science background. I want to become a professor in future.

I want to ask about the drawbacks and positive sides of joining a private university or Hochschule. Should I join one of them or wait for an offer from a public university in Germany?

Comment: Related to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72614/what-is-the-difference-between-hochschule-and-universit%c3%a4t-technische-universi

Comment: It's more towards credit and a Master's; my question is about becoming a professor after working in Fachhochschulen. Also, the concern of private universities is mentioned there.